# does gigabyte g41m combo has any integrated graphic card?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, motherboard

I have a motherboard that has intel chipset,motherboard - (gigabyte g41m combo), and i wanted to know that, does it have any integrated graphics which acts as an exception for the expanded graphic card geforce 210 as it is an out of date graphic card, and it does not give better performance. Also my motherboard has a vga port other than that of graphic card. And if it has the integrated graphic card where can i find the driver?

Answer (score 2):

Gigabyte's [product page](https://www.gigabyte.com/uk/Motherboard/GA-G41M-Combo-rev-13#ov) for the G41M says it runs an Intel [GMA X4500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_GMA#GMA_X4500) graphics chipset.

These products are from 2008 & are unlikely to be supported beyond Windows 7. Windows will be quite capable of finding the correct drivers for both the internal & PCI GPU - the GT 210 - so long as you are still on Win 7 or lower.

Neither of these were considered 'fast' when they were new, & at 12 years old you have probably discovered their limitations to run modern software.